# Is there a benefit to managing programs with a process manager instead of with init.d?

Tags: nginx, process, memcached, redis, supervisord

I'm using Redis, Memcached, and Nginx, to be specific, and Supervisor as the process manager, but any general information is helpful as well.

Each of the aforementioned programs when `apt-get` installed come with `/etc/init.d/` scripts. Are the `init.d` scripts provided to make setup easy for newcomers, and is there a notable benefit to deleting those `init.d` scripts and managing each program with something like Supervisor, which likely won't be gained through the use of an `init.d` script?

Comment: Actually deleting the scripts in init.d serves no purpose, and may only harm programs that expect the scripts to be there, and may confuse your fellow admins. It will also cause apt* utilities to complain about missing files. If you don't want to use them, ignore them.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski - oh :/ I'm glad you mentioned that. How can the `init.d` scripts be ignored though, if they're causing their respective programs to start on boot? Or, is something else handling that? For instance, what is causing Nginx to start on boot, and how could I (assuming this would be a good idea) stop that from happening, so that I could use Supervisor instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty well covered in the [Supervisord intro chapter](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html). Most services will run/work just fine with init.d, and that will be their default, out-of-the-box config. The process managers exist to give you expanded and finer-grained control and monitoring of your critical processes and services if that is something you desire/require.